# iPhone DatePicker with Actionsheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, datepicker

I am using this code to display a datePicker. When a textField was clicked, it appears. However, The "close" button overwraps the DatePicker. Do you know any way to move it down a little bit? thanks in advance.

```
-(IBAction)acsheet:(id)sender{

actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

//CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 0, 0);
pickerView1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;  



[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView1];

UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
closeButton.momentary = YES; 
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];    
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

[pickerView1 addTarget:self
             action:@selector(updateLabel:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] ;
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
toolBar.tag = 11;
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];



}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a `UIDatePicker` to appear when a `UITextField` becomes the first responder, then you should set the date picker to be the textfield's `inputView`.  Then when you tap on the field, the date picker will slide up *instead of* the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
```

change the **7.0f** and **30.f** to more positive values.and then try.

7.0f value is the origin.y of Button `// increase it to shift the button lower`

30.f value is the size.height of button`// increase it by the same amount you increase origin to keep proportional height`

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out by myself;

i've changed this line:

```
  pickerView1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```

into this:

```
pickerView1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 450)];
```